# Identify cloned DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom, medium-editor

I am using MediumEditor which a WYSIWYG editor using contenteditables. I need to assign different IDs to each element inside of the contentEditable, but (when you press `Enter`) the editor will clone a paragraph from an esiting one with all it's attributes. I am wondering if there is a way to identify the new `<p>` element from the one it was cloned from? The new element can be placed either before or after the existing one.

**UPDATE:**

Here's an example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/wwoh7e62/

```
<div id="container">
    <p id="myid" class="myclass" data-id="myid">some text</p>
</div>

<button onclick="doClone(); myFunc();">clone</button>

<script>
doClone = function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');

    var node = container.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].cloneNode(false);

    node.innerHTML = 'cloned node';

    container.appendChild(node);
}

myFunc = function () {
    console.log('my func');
}
</script>
```

The code in `doClone` I don't have access to. My code should reside in the `myFunc` function.

While I was typing the fiddle I realized that the solution will probably be in attaching an event listener (which is not cloned) and the new node will be the one that does not have the event listener.

**UPDATE:**

ids that were assigned previously need to stay the same as thay are used to identify particular nodes.

Comment: Could you give us a sample of generated code to see what is possible to do ?

Comment: I updated the question

Comment: Could you please post the relevant code here also instead of just having the link to JSFiddle?

Comment: not sure why you would ask for that, but I've added the code

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

1. Remove the id from "p"

   `<div id="container">
     <p class="myclass" data-id="myid">some text</p>
   </div>
   <button onclick="doClone(); myFunc();">clone</button>`
2. Then update them into your Func function :

   `var length = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("p").length;
   for(var i=0; i < length; i++) {
       document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("p")[i].id = i;
   }`

Does this help ?

Comment: No, sorry :) this can change the id of the original element potentially, which  I can not afford

Comment: And if you start the loop from i=1 ? https://jsfiddle.net/vma/51b9xuc1/1/

Comment: the cloned node can be inserted before the original, this will swap the ids